# What are the best workarounds for known problems with Hibernate's schema validation of floating point columns when using Oracle 10g?

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, orm

I have several Java classes with double fields that I am persisting via Hibernate.  For example, I have

```
@Entity
public class Node ...

  private double value;
```

When Hibernate's `org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect` creates the DDL for the Node table, it maps the value field to a "double precision" type.

```
create table MDB.Node (... value double precision not null, ...
```

It would appear that in Oracle, "double precision" is an alias for "float".  So, when I try to verify the database schema using the `org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.validateSchema()` method, Oracle appears to describe the value column as a "float". This causes Hibernate to throw the following Exception

```
org.hibernate.HibernateException: Wrong column type in DBO.ACL_RULE for column value. Found: float, expected: double precision
```

A very similar problem is listed in Hibernate's JIRA database as [HHH-1961](http://opensource.atlassian.com/projects/hibernate/browse/HHH-1961). I'd like to avoid doing anything that will break MySql, Postgres, and Sql Server support so extending the `Oracle10gDialect` appears to be the most promising of the workarounds mentioned in [HHH-1961](http://opensource.atlassian.com/projects/hibernate/browse/HHH-1961). But extending a Dialect is something I've never done before and I'm afraid there may be some nasty gotchas.  What is the best workaround for this problem that won't break our compatibility with MySql, Postgres, and Sql Server?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This is a [known limitation](https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=984507&start=0) of the schema validator, check [HHH-2315](http://opensource.atlassian.com/projects/hibernate/browse/HHH-2315). So you have three options here (actually four but I guess that deactivating validation is not wanted). Either:

- Use a `float` instead of a `double` at the Java level - this might not be an option though.
- Patch `org.hibernate.mapping.Table.validateColumns(Dialect dialect, Mapping mapping, TableMetadata tableInfo)` to add a special condition for this particular case - this isn't really a light option.
- Extends the `org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect` to make it use `float` for the SQL type `DOUBLE`

  ```
  public class MyOracle10gDialect extends Oracle10gDialect {
      public MyOracle10gDialect() {
          super();
      }
      protected void registerNumericTypeMappings() {
          super.registerNumericTypeMappings();
          registerColumnType( Types.DOUBLE, "float" );
      }
  }
  ```

The later option seems safe but will require some testing to see if it doesn't introduce any regression. I didn't look at Oracle's JDBC driver code, so I can't say how `float` and `double precision` differ at the driver level.

Comment: Extending the Oracle10gDialect the way you described fixes the validation issue and doesn't appear to cause any other problems.  Thanks!

Comment: @Jason You're welcome. BTW: The common way of recognizing a good answer is upvoting it ;-)

Answer (score 6):

just adding (columnDefinition = "NUMBER(9,2)") works!

```
@Column(name = "CREDIT_AMOUNT", columnDefinition = "NUMBER(9,2)")
@Basic
private double creditAmount;
```

Comment: This is actually the best answer!

Comment: It works, but if you are only going to work exclusively with Oracle. If you want to change the underlying DB, or have to support multiple DBs, it won't work. And you have to add this to every double field in your model. So no, not the best answer.

Answer (score 1):

There was a similar problem [HHH-1598](http://opensource.atlassian.com/projects/hibernate/browse/HHH-1598) with HSQL mappings of boolean fields, and a discussion of it [here](https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?p=2324183#2324183).

The solution I chose to use was in the discussion referenced above, with an extension of HSQLDialect.

I saw no problems with this, though I only use HSQL in tests.

It certainly doesn't interfere with any other DB.

Answer (score 1):

Use 'scale' attribute on your member.