# "ORA-01754: A table may contain only one column of type LONG" with only one Long type

Tags: java, database, oracle, hibernate

I am using hibernate with Oracle and tables are updated using hbm2ddl option at runtime before service starts.

Today, I started facing a weird issue where I came to know that table T has two long columns which is not supported in the Oracle.

```
@Table(name="table_t")
@Entity
public class T extends BaseEntity{

@Id
Long id;

@Column(name="col1")
Long col1;

@Column(name="col2")
Integer col2;

}
```

After facing the issue, I changed datatype of col1 to Integer(tables were not created in the DB) and tried re-running the application but it still fails with the same error.

Current schema appears like this:

```
@Table(name="table_t")
@Entity
public class T extends BaseEntity{

@Id
Long id;

@Column(name="col1")
Integer col1;

@Column(name="col2")
Integer col2;

}
```

Why is it happening? I tried cleaning, rebuilding and all.

Is meta info already stored somewhere? Or I am missing something else?

Thanks,

Comment: Those `Long` attributes should be mapped to a `NUMBER` column in Oracle, not to a `LONG` (`LONG` is a kind of `BLOB` datatype, it's not an integer type) - I would check if you are using the right Hibernate dialect.

Comment: Should it fail even with one Long?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2625600/what-are-the-best-workarounds-for-known-problems-with-hibernates-schema-validat/2627361#2627361 this is the dialect.

Comment: It's not a matter of "fail or not". The Oracle `LONG` datatype is completely the wrong choice for that.

Answer (score -1):

It's possible that the table has an unused long column.
You will not be able to see it but it needs to be dropped before you can add another one.
I have tried to explain it in this post:
http://international-dba.blogspot.co.uk/2014/01/ora-01754.html