# Tomcat not starting due to threadlocal issue

Tags: java, tomcat, thread-local

Whenever I deploy an application over Tomcat I am facing issue with the ThreadLocal, saying that Thread started but was never stopped. I have looked into other similar StackOverflow question in which the issue turned out to be in the code, which was evident from the stack trace. But in my case, the exception is coming from libraries I am using in the code, and not from something I have written in the code.

Here are the few exceptions, I can see in Tomcat console.

```
INFO: Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped already.  Could not load javolution.util.FastTable$FastTableIterator.  The eventual following stack trace is caused by an error thrown for debugging purposes as well as to attempt to terminate the thread which caused the illegal access, and has no functional impact.
java.lang.IllegalStateException
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1743)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1701)
        at javolution.util.FastTable.iterator(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadedByThisOrChild(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:2795)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:2713)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkThreadLocalsForLeaks(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:2668)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferences(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:2174)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.stop(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:2068)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappLoader.stopInternal(WebappLoader.java:661)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:224)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.stopInternal(StandardContext.java:5822)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:224)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:159)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:899)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:875)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:652)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:1091)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1980)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Also,

```
INFO: Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped already.  Could not load net.sf.ehcache.concurrent.LockType.  The eventual following stack trace is caused by an error thrown for debugging purposes as well as to attempt to terminate the thread which caused the illegal access, and has no functional impact.
java.lang.IllegalStateException
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1743)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1701)
        at net.sf.ehcache.store.FrontEndCacheTier.readLock(FrontEndCacheTier.java:642)
        at net.sf.ehcache.store.FrontEndCacheTier.getKeys(FrontEndCacheTier.java:495)
        at net.sf.ehcache.Cache.getKeys(Cache.java:1878)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294)
```

And finally these two exceptions.

```
Feb 22, 2016 8:32:45 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks
SEVERE: The web application [/test] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [test.util.persistence.PersistenceFacade$1] (value [test.util.persistence.PersistenceFacade$1@2c600630]) and a value of type [java.util.Stack] (value [[]]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.


INFO: Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped already.  Could not load org.apache.http.pool.AbstractConnPool$3.  The eventual following stack trace is caused by an error thrown for debugging purposes as well as to attempt to terminate the thread which caused the illegal access, and has no functional impact.
java.lang.IllegalStateException
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1743)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1701)
        at org.apache.http.pool.AbstractConnPool.closeIdle(AbstractConnPool.java:493)
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingClientConnectionManager.closeIdleConnections(PoolingClientConnectionManager.java:288)
        at com.amazonaws.http.IdleConnectionReaper.run(IdleConnectionReaper.java:127)
```

Is there a solution to issue? I have tried things like restarting the server, restarting the machine and even a new installation of Tomcat but this issue doesn't seem to go away.

Comment: Is that test class part of your WAR deployment?  If yes, why is it there at all?  Test code does not belong in a WAR.

Comment: Actually this is the name of the project I am trying to deploy.

Comment: What ThreadLocal are you starting when the application is brought up?

Comment: This is how I am using ThreadLocal. 

private static ThreadLocal<ServletContext> ctxByThread = new ThreadLocal<ServletContext>();

Comment: What is that thread doing?  The Java EE standard would recommend that you leave multithread behavior to the app server, Tomcat.

Comment: Are you using Hibernate?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2625600/what-are-the-best-workarounds-for-known-problems-with-hibernates-schema-validat

Comment: Yes I agree. I will be fixing it. But I am wondering how shall I remove those dead threads from my machine. 

And to answer your question I am using the server context as 

protected void service(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
  ctxByThread.set(getServletContext());
  super.service(req, resp);
  ctxByThread.set(null);
 }

Comment: Yes I am using Hibernate, but I am not facing this issue due to that. Nowhere in the stack trace, I can see Hibernate causing an issue

Comment: Please stop posting code showing how you acquire the thread.  I'd like to know what it's doing.  You should ask yourself if that task is necessary.  Turn it off, remove it, and see if Tomcat comes up.  Are you using Hibernate?  There are validator issues that will cause this exception.

Comment: The search I did, and the links it returned, suggests that Hibernate did cause this problem.  You need to dig more.